# Know the comment for last commit when I update my svn working copy

Tags: svn, pysvn

I am using PySVN and the work-bench for my svn needs and I previously used to use subclipse. When I update my working copy, neither of these tools told me the reason why someone has committed the last commit.

I want it to show along with the new revision number, the comment given for the last commit and by whom. I am quite good with python myself, I tried to find help on this in the pysvn documentation, but nothing. (Or does pysvn already have this feature ??)

I couldn't find the comment for committing a particular line even in the annotate view.. am I interpreting this 'comment' wrongly.. is it supposed to be hidden :?

If anyone could point me to the right direction...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a quick script

```
#!/bin/bash
svn up
svn log --limit=1
```

Comment: sweet! I remember I used to write these sweet little scripts when I was using linux :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about PySVN but from command line you can use, I suppose:

```
svn log -v
```

to get last commit comment full informations.
Surely PySVN has the possibility to do that.

Looking to the doc of [PySVN](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_callback_get_log_message) I found this example about   **pysvn.Client.callback_get_log_message**

```
import pysvn

log_message = "reason for change"
def get_log_message():
    return rc, log_message

client = pysvn.Client()
client.callback_get_log_message = get_log_message
```

"...The callback_get_log_message is called when a log message is required to complete the current command. Return the True in rc and a log message as a string. Returning False in rc will cause the command to be cancelled. An empty log_message is not allowed and may cause the command to be cancelled.
Unicode strings cannot be handled. If you have a unicode string, convert it to UTF-8..."

Comment: Thanks so much, but isn't that to be used when I am giving a comment.. I think this http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_log is more appropriate to GET the last/previous log message(s)

Comment: Yeah, pysvn.Client.log is wrapping "svn log" command. As already said 
I don't know about PySVN, just surfing on google :-) !

Answer (score 1):

You can get the log info from pretty much any Subversion client tool Keep in mind the last commit log message may not tell you anything useful - there may have been 50 commits since you last updated, so **you really need to see all log messages since you last committed**.

Additionally, you may want to make use of the [pre-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html) to enforce entering a message on commit. That way you'll always have something to read :)

Comment: wow, we are just a team of 3+1 tester, so there wont be so many commits at once :P and, we all write comments.. :)